# VScode корректная настройка task.json для c++

Tags: c++, json, visual-studio-code, task

Пишу на С++ в VScode, по началу казалось совсем не удобной штукой, но когда разобрался с  компиляцией через терминал и почитав пару статей про работу в данной среде, оказалось все не так уж и плохо и даже наоборот, начинаешь привыкать и писать небольшие программы очень быстро и удобно.
Так вот, компилируем и запускаем мы файл с помощью файла конфигурации task.json. Там же мы можем прикрутить всякие удобные штуки, к примеру, чтобы чистился терминал, при запуске новой программы или фокусировался на терминале, после запуска.
Собственно, какое-то время назад вычитал на просторах microsoft, что в "presentation" : {"focus" -> отвечал за тот самый фокус на терминале, а "clear" -> очищал терминал}, но ни один из них не работает. Если кто-то знает почему и как исправить, буду очень рад)

```
{
"tasks": [
    {
        "type": "cppbuild",
        "label": "C/C++: g++-13 сборка активного файла",
        "command": "/usr/bin/g++-13",
        "args": [
            "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
            "-g",
            "${file}",
            "-o",
            "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
        ],
        "options": {
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
        },
        "problemMatcher": [
            "$gcc"
        ],
        "group": {
            "kind": "build",
            "isDefault": true
        },
        "presentation": {
            "reveal": "always",
            "panel": "dedicated",
            "focus": true,
            "clear": false
        }
        "detail": "Задача создана отладчиком."
    }
],
"version": "2.0.0"}
```

P.S. Данный таск для убунту, для винды немного отличается